# Нужно ли хранить презентер MVP?

Tags: android, mvp

В разных описаниях архитектуры MVP встречал разный подход к хранению\уничтожению presenter. Кто-то сериализует его, и затем в `onCreate()` восстанавливает. Кто-то никак не сохраняет и каждый раз в  `onCreate()` создает новый.

Вопросы:

1. Зачем кто-то хранит **peresenter**, в нем ведь никогда не будет закешированных данных. Плюс, который я вижу, это не тратить каждый раз ресурсы на создание нового **presenter** в `onCreate()`. Но вместо этого нам придется каждый раз сериализовывать и десераилизовывать его. Оно того стоит?
2. Зачем некоторые перед созданием **presenter** проверяют поле **mPresenter** в нашей вьюхе на **null**, ведь если вызывается `onCreate()`, то вьюхи либо не было никогда, либо она была уничтожена вместе со всеми полями и
   **mPeresnter** в любом случае будет **null**.
3. Зачем вызывается `detachView()` в `onDestroy()`, если после
   уничтожения активити ссылка на **presenter** перестанет существовать
   и GC скорее всего удалит его, вместе с ссылкой на **view**. Чтобы
   это было не скорее всего,а наверняка?

Лучшая практика - это создавать новый **presenter** в `onCreate()` или восстанавливать старый и атачить к нему новый экземпляр view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Часто нужно чтобы презентер жил во время процесса смены конфигурации, смены ориентации экрана, например. В этом случае какой-то длительный сетевой запрос может быть начат при одной ориентации, а закончен быть при другой или в процессе смены ориентации. В таких случаях презентеры хранят не в активти/фрагментах, но в отдельном месте, кое не зависит от жизненного цикла. Например в синглтоне, коий содержит мапу с презентерами по их ID. При таком подходе презентер создаётся если его нет в мапе, уведомляетя о прикреплении вьюхи и об откреплении оной. Так он сможет обработать ситуацию прихода данных во время "мёртвой вью" не нарвавшись на `NPE` и сможет продолжать работу пока пересоздаётся активити.

В любом случае подходов много на разные случаи. В каких-то случаях поворотов экрана не будет, в других же надо данные пришедшие во время поворота отобразить и используют `ViewState` для хранения состояния вьюхи, кое к ней применяют после её прикрепления к презентеру.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд пересоздание самый простой сценарий. Умер фрагмент - убили презентер. 
Да, можно хранить в мап синглтона, а можно доверить управление жизненным циклом презентера dagger с его скоупами. Тогда останеться только аттачить и детачить созданные и убиваемые вью к презентерам.
Хороший подход использовать вместо presenter новый компонент viewModel с его liveData. Можно очень просто сэттить закешированные данные если вью умерало и восстанавливалось. ViewModel не привязано к жизненному циклу вью. очень удобно. 
Для сэттинга закешированных данных классно использовать паттерн MVI. Подробно есть в блоге Тинькофф на хабре.